# Spring Security rename login form tags name

Tags: forms, spring-security

I Spring Security Login form we have the following form

```
<form name='f' action='/j_spring_security_check' method='POST'> 
 <table> 
    <tr><td>User:</td><td><input type='text' name='j_username' value=''></td></tr> 
    <tr><td>Password:</td><td><input type='password' name='j_password'/></td></tr> 
    <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="submit" type="submit"/></td></tr> 
    <tr><td colspan='2'><input name="reset" type="reset"/></td></tr> 
  </table> 
</form>
```

I know how to modify action attribute on this form (using  `login-processing-url="/login"`)
My question is how can I change j_username & j_password tags names, to be username and password?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an alternative way for your request :
[Spring - Security : how are login username and password bound to the authentication-provider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599487/spring-security-how-are-login-username-and-password-bound-to-the-authenticati/1600918#1600918)
[Spring Security 3- How to customize username/password parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2483992/spring-security-3-how-to-customize-username-password-parameters/2484817#2484817)

But the best approach is update to [**Spring Security 3.1.0**](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/downloads.html) (latest version is RC2, GA may release in few months from now), with the [**new configuration**](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SEC-1445) in `form-login` :

```
<beans:beans>
  <http>
    <form-login username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password" />
  </http>
</beans:beans>
```